# Why can .format() not be used separately from the declaration?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

Can someone explain to me what is going on with the .format() method that it only works off a string declaration and not on a variable containing a string?

Below are the example of the working and failing code followed by the output of each

```
# This works fine
s = "{0} \n" \
    "{1} \n" \
    "{2}\n" \
    .format("Hello", "world", "from a multiline string")
print(s)

# This does not
f = "{0} \n" \
    "{1} \n" \
    "{2}\n"

f.format("Hello", "world", "from a multiline string")
print(f)
```

respective output

```
Hello 
world 
from a multiline string

{0} 
{1} 
{2}
```

I have tried this with no numbers in braces(`{}`) as well as by assigning names (`{aname}`) and passing keyword arguments. I'd like to understand the difference between the first and second examples in how the format method processes them, and if there is a way to format a variable containing a string separate from the actual declaration.

Comment: Because `.format()` is a method of `str` object.

Comment: @mika72 f contains a str object `print(type(f))` outputs `<class 'str'>`

Comment: You missed a detail, basically a typo: `print(f.format("Hello", "world", "from a multiline string"))` is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working, but you will need to reassign it back since it is not in-place (= it creates a new string object, just like any other `str` method).

```
f = "{0} \n" \
    "{1} \n" \
    "{2}\n"
f = f.format("Hello", "world", "from a multiline string")
print(f)
#  Hello 
#  world 
#  from a multiline string
```

Comment: Oh my word... This is what happens when you code at 4:30 AM and you're used to sleeping. I'll accept it as soon as the time lapses. Thanks DeepSpace

Answer (score 5):

because `.format` function returns the formatted string.

It doesn't format the string on which it's called, but it will return you a new string object having the formatted result.